# change verilog 16x4 unidirectional mux to bidirectional mux

Tags: verilog, mux

I wrote the following code to implement four 16:4 muxes:

```
module coder(
    selCh0, selCh1, selCh2, selCh3, 
    outCh0, outCh1, outCh2, outCh3,
    inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3
);
    input  wire [1:0] selCh0, selCh1, selCh2, selCh3;
    output wire [3:0] outCh0, outCh1, outCh2, outCh3;
    input  wire [3:0] inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3;

    mux_16x4 ch0(selCh0, inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3, outCh0);
    mux_16x4 ch1(selCh1, inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3, outCh1);
    mux_16x4 ch2(selCh2, inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3, outCh2);
    mux_16x4 ch3(selCh3, inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3, outCh3);
endmodule

module mux_16x4(sel, enc0, enc1, enc2, enc3, out);
    input wire [1:0] sel;
    input wire [3:0] enc0, enc1, enc2, enc3;
    output reg [3:0] out;

    always @(sel, enc0, enc1, enc2, enc3)
    begin
        case ({sel})
            2'b00: out <= enc0;
            2'b01: out <= enc1;
            2'b10: out <= enc2;
            2'b11: out <= enc3;
            default: out <= 4'b0;
        endcase;
    end
endmodule
```

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a more efficient and/or better way to do this? I'm learning, so I don't have any particular issues with the code I wrote, but I thought I'd check to see if it could be improved.
2. I need to reverse the fourth bit of each 4:1 mux. Right now, every bit in each inEncN bus is an input and every bit in each outChY bus is an output. I wrote it this way at first to see if it would work, but the real hardware needs a signal to go the other way.

To try to be more concise, I'll explain with a particular set of signals. Right now, the bits in outCh0[3:0] are all outputs. I really need outCh0[3] to be an input and for it to map to whichever inEncN[3] bus is selected by the select signals. Therefore, I also need all of the inEncN[3] signals to be outputs instead of inputs like the other three bits in each respective bus.

I tried to make all of the buses in question `inout` instead of `input` or `output`, but I couldn't get that to compile regardless of what I tried.

The code shown above compiles to 32 logic elements, which leaves eight spares. Fitting the code in 40 or less logic elements would be a huge win, but I have an acceptable plan B.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "outCh0[3] to be an input and for it to map to whichever inEncN[3] bus is selected"? It seems to me that would be the same as `sel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any bidirectional signals here, you just need to redefine your ports a bit.  With system verilog you could pass multidimensional arrays as ports which would make this code a bit more compact.  You could also create structs to contain the 3 inputs and 1 output in one object.  However, this is a verilog question so we will do it that way:

```
module coder(
  selCh0, selCh1, selCh2, selCh3, 
  outCh0, outCh1, outCh2, outCh3,
  inCh0, inCh1, inCh2, inCh3,
  inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3,
  outEnc0, outEnc1, outEnc2, outEnc3      
);
  input  [1:0] selCh0, selCh1, selCh2, selCh3;

  input  [2:0] inEnc0, inEnc1, inEnc2, inEnc3;
  output       outEnc0, outEnc1, outEnc2, outEnc3;

  output [2:0] outCh0, outCh1, outCh2, outCh3;
  input        inCh0, inCh1, inCh2, inCh3;

  wire [2:0] inEnc [0:3];
  wire       inCh [0:3];

  assign inEnc[0] = inEnc0;
  assign inEnc[1] = inEnc1;
  assign inEnc[2] = inEnc2;
  assign inEnc[3] = inEnc3;

  assign inCh[0] = inCh0;
  assign inCh[1] = inCh1;
  assign inCh[2] = inCh2;
  assign inCh[3] = inCh3;

  assign outCh0 = inEnc[selCh0];
  assign outCh1 = inEnc[selCh1];
  assign outCh2 = inEnc[selCh2];
  assign outCh3 = inEnc[selCh3];

  assign outEnc0 = inCh[selCh0];
  assign outEnc1 = inCh[selCh1];
  assign outEnc2 = inCh[selCh2];
  assign outEnc3 = inCh[selCh3];

endmodule
```

Here is it repeated with arrays as ports in system verilog.  This is also parameterized for flexibility in # of channels.  Since the number of channels might not be a power of 2, we have to check that selCh is a legal value.  If not, assign a default value to the outputs.  The `$clog2` function is used to calculate the minimum number of bits needed to select from `NUMCH` inputs:

```
module coder #(parameter NUMCH=4) (
  input [$clog2(NUMCH)-1:0] selCh[NUMCH],

  input      [2:0] inEnc[NUMCH],
  output reg       outEnc[NUMCH],

  output reg [2:0] outCh[NUMCH],
  input            inCh[NUMCH]
  );

  always_comb begin
    for (int i=0; i<NUMCH; i++) begin
      if(selCh[i]<NUMCH) begin
        outCh[i] = inEnc[selCh[i]];
        outEnc[i] = inCh[selCh[i]];
      end
      else begin
        outCh[i] = '0;
        outEnc[i] = '0;
      end
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and code! I think i understand what you're saying with the System Verilog example. It certainly looks much cleaner and more maintainable. I figured there had to be a way to use multidimensional arrays, but I couldn't figure it out. This answer really helps me in several ways.

Comment: If you can use the system verilog syntax I would go for it.  The tools I use (VCS and Incisive) both fully support it as far as I can tell.  The hoops you have to jump through sometimes with verilog to do this kind of thing really makes hard to understand code.  I would stick to the simple stuff for design since you can easily get into areas that are not synthesizable since the SV language has many features which are only meant for verification.